# Apple iPhone 5s 2 Apple IDs

Tags: iphone

When you set up your Apple ID when you first get your phone can you set up another once you have signed in on that account?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes, long answer, it's going to be a lot more trouble than it's worth. You'll have to constantly swap between them to get downloads/updates etc.

Each app/book/tune etc, even the iOS itself belongs to the account that purchased it.

If you really must have 2 IDs on one phone, the best solution is probably to set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) & join both IDs to the same 'family'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to sign out the existing 1, then you are free to login using different Apple ID. Apple ID is not tied to only 1 particular device. However only 1 logon Apple ID at 1 time.